# Why does WordPress remove my code element's class attribute?

Tags: wordpress

I have written the following HTML into the text editor of a WordPress post:

```
<code class="language-javascript">jsonFile.image</code>
```

When I preview the page, I get this:

```
<code>jsonFile.image</code>
```

I have other blocks like this one:

```
<pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-json">{
  "image": "image.jpg",
  "_image_comment": "This image should not be displayed"
}</code></pre>
```

These are left intact when the post is previewed.

Is this happening because of my theme, or is this something WordPress Core is doing?

Comment: can you share the url of your site..

Comment: which theme you are using? in default theme class attrbute not removed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCyoc.png

Comment: @RajkumarGour https://raddevon.com

Comment: @vel I'm using a theme called [Typology](https://mekshq.com/theme/typology/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markdown feature of the [Jetpack plugin](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) was causing the classes to be dropped when I saved the post. Not clear why it was affecting some and not others, but it was definitely the issue.